# What is the kernel module "hid_microsoft"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

The lsmod-command shows the odd module. The command "modprobe -a hid_microsoft" does not reveal anything. What is it?

```
$ modinfo hid_microsoft
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.28-15-generic/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-microsoft.ko
license:        GPL
srcversion:     3FE2E2F2EE89174E885204A
alias:          hid:b0005v0000045Ep00000701
alias:          hid:b0003v0000045Ep0000009D
alias:          hid:b0003v0000045Ep00000713
alias:          hid:b0003v0000045Ep000000F9
alias:          hid:b0003v0000045Ep000000DB
alias:          hid:b0003v0000045Ep0000003B
depends:
vermagic:       2.6.28-15-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 586
```

Comment: Isn't it obvious? It's a hidden effort by Microsoft to take over your computer! Thank God for their coding and code naming standards, we found out. Run for your lives, everyone :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "hid" part probably refers to [Human Interface Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class), which is a USB term for "keyboard or mouse". The "microsoft" part might refer to an interface to a Microsoft mouse or something.

Comment: You are probably right! I have a Microsoft keyboard, never thought that it had to have a kernel module for it.

Answer (score 12):

According the [kernel driver database](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/HID_MICROSOFT.html), hid_microsoft adds support for Microsoft USB devices that are not compliant with the HID standard.  The [source code](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git-repos/rtg/linux-2.6/drivers/hid/hid-microsoft.c) comments allude to handling for "special" features on MS keyboards and wireless devices.